# php json_decode returns null every time

Tags: php

I am using `json_decode` on `file_get_contents("php://input")` but I get null every time.
I output `file_get_contents("php://input")` and got output in this format `a=1&b=2`.
How can I convert this to an array?

Comment: Show us the form or script sending the input! This is not json, but rather two variables a=1 and b=2 posted from a script/form

Comment: Well, **that's not JSON.** Just use `$_POST`, you data should be there already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `json_decode`?! Use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-str.php)